# How to configure Apache Rivet on openSUSE with YaST2

Tags: apache-httpd, opensuse, tcl

I need to configure my Apache web local server to view Tcl Apache Rivet web dynamic applications.

The problem I run into is my browser forces me to download the file, so Apache doesn't interpret the file before I visit the application.

If I visit the root folder, the index.rvt is directly downloaded. So even Apache does a minimal job.

Did somebody have the same problem and sorted it out before ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't seem like a YaST thing (YaST will only do very basic things for Apache)...you might find something in the advanced setting where you can add the module.

However, you're probably going to still have to make a file in /etc/apache2/conf.d to tell Apache what to do when it comes across such a file.

Here is a [link](https://tcl.apache.org/rivet/manual2.1/installation.html) for some more information.

In case the link goes down\further detail for OpenSuSE **only**:

Edit `/etc/sysconfig/apache2`

Look for the section called `APACHE_MODULES` and inside of the quotes add rivet. Save, exit, and restart apache `rcapache2 restart`.

If you're lucky, that'll enable rivet, but it probably won't. If that is the case undo the changes. Save and restart apache (this way we are back at square 1).

You'll now need to make a file called `/etc/apache2/conf.d/rivet.conf`

Add the following (you may need to adjust the location):

```
LoadModule rivet_module /usr/lib64/apache2/mod_rivet.so

AddType application/x-httpd-rivet .rvt
AddType application/x-rivet-tcl .tcl

AddType 'application/x-httpd-rivet;charset=utf-8' rvt

DirectoryIndex index.tcl index.rvt
```

Save that and restart apache.

That should be a good start, but realize that I've never used the rivet module so the rivet.conf might not be correct. Let me know and I'll edit that so we have the correct info.

Comment: I forgot to thank you. It worked with your help. But, I went back to PHP. Hopefully I could go Lua, Tcl, Perl or even Go in the future. Thanks!

Comment: If it worked, would you mind marking it as accepted? This way people in the future have an answer.